# VB.Net - List all folders shared over network

Tags: vb.net

I've searched for this question for a really long time now. And i still can't find a decent one.

I need to be able to view all of the shared folders that can bee accessed by other computers via LAN. I found that not all shared folders are accessible by connected computers, that's how i get a problem. Mine lists all shared folders on local (even the ones not accessible by connected PCs).

From this post:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541736-RESOLVED-shared-folder-list

-Nico

Comment: what is the environment? Domain, Workgroup?

Comment: Good luck. I have tried lots of API's and have not been able to get what I want.